# when i new a project in android studio error found in priview Render problem

Tags: android

Problem:

```
Render problem
Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

[image]

A lot of people said change theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to  `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` but still not solved. Of course I don't want to to this every time when I start a new project.

This problem gradle:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "three.my.test.newtextapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Have you built the project yet?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the 28 SDK to 27 and use 27.1.1 dependencies. And if you still want to use 28 then use 28-rc1. Hope this helps you to solve the problem.